# QGIS: spatialite incorrect string concatenation when loading layers

Tags: qgis, spatialite, well-known-text, concatenation

I am trying to draw some polygons in spatialite using the DB Manager in QGIS. However

```
select 1 as id, st_geomfromtext('POLYGON((0 0,0 '||random()||','||random()||' '||random()||','||random()||' 0,0 0))',31256) as geom
```

throws the following error

```
Data source is invalid (In ExecuteSQL(): sqlite3_prepare_v2(select 1 as id, st_geomfromtext('POLYGON((0 0,0 '):
              incomplete input)
```

which gives me the impression that the concatenation doesn't work this way. But how else is this supposed to work?

Win10 1607, QGIS 3.14.16, Spatialite 4.3.0a
and on
Ubuntu 20.04, QGIS 3.10.8, Spatialite 4.3.0a
[image: layer looks fine in db manager but it can not be added to canvas]

Comment: Please add the exact QGIS version you are using (copy&paste `<QGIS> | Help | About`), and details of the layers you are working on, if any. I cannot reproduce with  *QGIS 3.14.1-Pi*, *SQLite 3.31.1* and *SpatiaLite 4.3.0a* and *no* layer as source.

Comment: version specs added. no layer is used because `st_geomfromtext('POLYGON((0 0,0 10,10 10,10 0,0 0))',31256) as geom` generates a nice square out of the blue.

Comment: It fails if you run the concatenation within the geopackage section. Even `select 1 as id, 'a' || 'b' as txt` will fail, stopping the query at `||`) (well, `execute` is fine, you can `load` the layer/table but the content will be incorrect). It will however work if you run the same statement in the `virtual layer` section.  QGIS LTR 3.10, SQLite 3.29

Comment: well, thank you. out of curiosity: I know the gpkq provider is somewhat limited but why does it show on such a imho simple task?

Comment: @maxwhere it depends on the point of view... a user will say it is a bug, an open source developer will say it is a limited feature and a commercial developer will say it is by design :-)  (bad) joke aside, you may want to [report](https://github.com/qgis/qgis/issues) the issue